# Import Fact Table Data from Multiple Tables and Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I am trying to build the fact table in this snowflake schema: [!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCHaF.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCHaF.png)

I am using this database: [enter link description here](https://github.com/scottsimpson/restaurant-database)

I am using SSMS, and when I right click my warehouse and choose import data then the query approach, I am left with the issue of having to fit all those queries for my measures into 1 big query which I had issues writing, but ended up with this only solution that had no errors:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID AS OrderID,
Events.EventID AS EventID,
Customers.CustomerID AS CustomerID,
Dishes.DishID AS DishID,
NormAvgTable.AverageNormalCustomerCount,
EveAvgTable.AverageEventCustomerCount,
FavDishTable.CustomerFavDishOrderCount,
EveRevTable.TotalEventsRevenue,
DishOrderCtTable.DishOrderCount,
CustomerRev.CustomerOrderRevenue,
BdayCtTable.CustomerBirthdayOrderCount
FROM Orders, Events, Customers, Dishes
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT AVG(count) AS AverageNormalCustomerCount
    FROM (
    SELECT Events.EventID, COUNT(Orders.CustomerID) AS count
    FROM Customers
    INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN OrdersDishes
    ON Orders.OrderID = OrdersDishes.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Events
    ON CAST(Orders.OrderDate AS DATE) <> CAST(Events.Date AS DATE)
    GROUP BY Events.EventID
) AS CtTable
) AS NormAvgTable
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT AVG(count) AS AverageEventCustomerCount
    FROM (
    SELECT Events.EventID, COUNT(Orders.CustomerID) AS count
    FROM Customers
    INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN OrdersDishes
    ON Orders.OrderID = OrdersDishes.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Events
    ON CAST(Orders.OrderDate AS DATE) = CAST(Events.Date AS DATE)
    GROUP BY Events.EventID
)AS EveCtTable
) EveAvgTable
CROSS JOIN(
SELECT Customers.CustomerID AS CustomerID, COUNT(Orders.OrderID)
AS CustomerFavDishOrderCount
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrdersDishes
ON Customers.FavoriteDish = OrdersDishes.DishID
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
) AS FavDishTable
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT SUM(Dishes.Price)
AS TotalEventsRevenue
FROM Events
INNER JOIN Orders
ON CAST(Orders.OrderDate AS DATE) = CAST(Events.Date AS DATE)
INNER JOIN OrdersDishes
ON Orders.OrderID = OrdersDishes.OrderID
INNER JOIN Dishes
ON OrdersDishes.DishID = Dishes.DishID
GROUP BY Events.EventID
) AS EveRevTable
CROSS JOIN(
SELECT  Dishes.DishID AS DishID, COUNT(OrdersDishes.OrdersDishesID) 
AS DishOrderCount
FROM OrdersDishes
INNER JOIN Dishes
ON Dishes.DishID = OrdersDishes.DishID
GROUP BY Dishes.DishID
) AS DishOrderCtTable
CROSS JOIN(
SELECT Orders.CustomerID AS CustomerID, SUM(Dishes.Price)
AS CustomerOrderRevenue
FROM OrdersDishes
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Orders.OrderID = OrdersDishes.OrderID
INNER JOIN Dishes
ON OrdersDishes.DishID = Dishes.DishID
GROUP BY Orders.CustomerID
) AS CustomerRev
CROSS JOIN(
SELECT Customers.CustomerID AS CustomerID, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) 
AS CustomerBirthdayOrderCount
FROM Orders, Customers
WHERE DAY(Orders.OrderDate) = DAY(Customers.Birthday)
AND MONTH(Orders.OrderDate) = MONTH(Customers.Birthday)
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
) AS BdayCtTable
```

Aside from the fact that it looks very ugly, it gave me no errors and kept copying up to **50 Million** records, which I had to stop the wizard at because it kept going even further.

What is a better query I can use/how to optimize mine (what are mistakes in it).

Comment: Why do you have to do it all in one query?

Comment: @Charlieface im trying to import the data from the linked database into the snowflake schema i provided in the picture using SSMS and SQL server, in the import wizard it appears i have to put all in only 1 query

Comment: Your use of multiple  `cross join` here is clearly wrong. I think you've used `cross join` here more times than I have in the last 10 years! Your first 4 tables' rows are all multiplied together (this is NOT how to write good SQL), so if each only had 10 rows each, that's 10,000 rows straight away. This is then multipled by the subsequent cross join, the result of which is multiplied by the next cross join etc.

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Worse is the use of both old and current styles.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to build a proper schema from a single query. Find a way of importing multiple tables. You can just click "import" multiple times I think

Comment: @Charlieface i was trying! but sadly it kept telling me that this fills the rest with NULL and those columns dont allow it

Comment: @Stu yeah i figured that out sadly, but couldnt figure out how else to join them as they dont really have something to join by, fact tables are weird!

Answer (score 0):

Two issues - Record count high and SQL looks complex/unreadable.
Record count is high because of cross join. You need to set some join condition between subqueries and tables. For example, you mentioned below tables but no joins `FROM Orders, Events, Customers, Dishes`. I am not sure about requirements so, here are my thoughts/solutions. -

1. Make a bare minimum SQL with only Orders table. Then keep on adding joins and check count, time consumed. if higher than expectation try to tune that join. proceed till last table.
2. Cross join is always expensive - try using inner or left. Also few tables doenst have join conditions which produces Cartesian join and thus making result count huge.
3. Use sqlformat.org/ to make your sql beautiful :)
4. If point#1 above becomes complex, make two SQLs and create an intermediate table to do this. You dont have to put all logic in one SQL. Can break it as well.
5. Check index in each table and see if you can use them in your SQL.

Comment: the requirement is to build the schema i provided in the picture from the linked database! so im not sure how to link orderID for example with my other measurements, theres no join required and i just wanted the result of all those tables to be in 1 but without repeated rows!